# how to complete a countdown challenge in c programming

Tags: c, xcode4

Could somebody help me with solving this. I'm almost there I just need a little push. I'm supposed to have the output count down from 99 and count down by 3(I solved that correctly), but I also need the output to print "found one" if it comes across a number divisible by 5! I need help with that. heres what I have so far. Note that the code doesn't print "found one" even when i have the right function in that solves dividends.

```
#include <objc/objc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 99;
    while (i > -1) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i = i-3;
    }
{
if (i%5==0) printf("found one\n");
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably learn the basic syntax of the language first, and then ask questions later, instead of typing in jibberish and then posting it to SO.

Comment: look, i know the basic syntax of the language...btw im sorry for shouting(i didn't realize my CAPS key was turned on

Comment: @PaulTomblin: That's hardly jibberish, but rather a valid novice question.  Unfortunately (imho) the homework tag is gone.  When we had that tag, one could just not read questions with that tag if one did not want to spend time helping novices.

Comment: @EricJ, the question as originally posted contained something that was so far distant from any valid syntax for any known computer language as to make you question whether the person asking the question had even read chapter one of his text book. Thus, "jibber ish".

Comment: well i guess you dont know c then

Comment: Hi user, I edited your code to indent it properly. When you use proper indentation, it makes it so much easier to see the problems in the code as our eyes are trained to see the code blocks much easier this way. For instance, it's now easier to see the problem [Eric J points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12845171/552792) with your if statement being outside your while loop. Also, you're using the wrong curly braces at the beginning of your code blocks, and one code block doesn't seem to be associated with an if or while statement. Remember, indenting will save you a lot of grief! Good luck:)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the modulo operator

```
if (i % 5 == 0) // The number is divisible by 5
```

The modulo operator calculates the remainder after division.  If the remainder is zero, then the integer number was exactly divisible by the modulo operand, in this case 5.

Comment: thanks for reminding me...since you seem like a person who doesn't taunt those who are relatively new to the language, ill ask you one more thing. I inserted that into my code, but now the code doesn't say "found one" when it has found a dividend of 5. heres my code now.

Comment: Your new code will only ever test the *final* value if *i* because you don't have `if (i%5==0) printf("found one\n");` inside your *while* loop.

Comment: Also... don't forget to upvote helpful answers and accept the most helpful/most correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint. The modulus (%) operator returns the remainder after integer division. So 11 % 10 = 1, and 15 % 5 = 0. Given your code, you should be able to go from there!

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(i%5 == 0)` instead. This checks to see if it is divided by 5 – that there are no remainders.